# Print When Expression in iReport comparing 2 string

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, ireport

Can I put more than one condition at print when expression? And can you please give the syntax. For example,

```
If Field Value = 'Cancelled' then Print Grey Color
Feild Value = 'Proposed ' then Print Black Color
```

Etc

Based on the Field value, I need to change the color of the text field.

I used this syntax

```
$F{status_Current}.StringValue() ='Canceled'? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
```

But it's throwing an Error.

Can someone please give the proper syntax for this

Comment: What is the type of ***status_Current*** field? If **java.lang.String** then correct syntax in Java 5 will be: `$F{status_Current}.equals("Canceled") ? true : false`. For Java 4: `$F{status_Current}.equals("Canceled") ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the variable status_Current is of type string you should be able to compare using

```
$F{status_Current}.equals("Canceled")? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE
```

But it sounds like you may be trying to do some conditional formatting which I haven't had to do yet.
I researched a bit and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415989/using-conditional-formatting-in-ireport) hope it helps.

Good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

$F{status_Current}.StringValue().equals("Canceled") ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

1. Type of the field 'status_Current' is String

> $F{status_Current}.equals("Canceled")? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE

2. Type of the field 'status_Current' is NOT String

> $F{status_Current}.StringValue().equals("Canceled") ? Boolean.TRUE :
>   Boolean.FALSE