# Using conditional formatting in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report providing a table of data. The report works great so far.
Now I need to colourise some cells according to their content value.
I used to include the colour scheme in the Text Field Expression, for instance:

```
($F{MyBooleanValue}==true)?"<style backcolor='green'>PASS</style>":"<style backcolor='red'>FAIL</style>"
```

That works but it is quite dirty and a hell to manage and re-use.

So I turned to the *Conditional formatting* feature. I defined a based style called *Colourised*. Then two very basic conditional styles:

```
Colourised:  
    opaque = true  
pass:  
    opaque = true  
    Condition Expression = "true"  
    Backcolor = [51,255,51]
fail:  
    opaque = true  
    Condition Expression = "false"  
    Backcolor = [255,102,102]
```

This should normally change the background colour of cells to green (independently from the cell value).

Now I try to use this formatting on my cell using the following properties, but the cells remain desperately white.

```
MyCell:  
    opaque = true  
    Text Field Expression = "$F{MyBooleanValue}"  
    Style = "Colourised"
```

I also set the evaluation property

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.style.evaluation.time.enabled" value="true"/>
```

Any hints? Is there something I overlooked?

Comment: Can you post the snippet of *jrxml* file with styles definitions and with styled *textField*?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after a bit of digging, I found that the cell propertie:

```
MyCell:
    Markup = "styled"
```

needed to be set to:

```
MyCell:
    Markup = "none"
```

Then the background display the proper colour.